# Puppeteer: How to listen to a specific response?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm tinkering with the headless chrome node api called `puppeteer`.

I'm wondering how to listen to a specific request response and how to act in consequence.

I have look at events `requestfinish` and `response` but it gives me **all** the request/responses already performed in the page.

How can I achieve commented behaviour?

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/examples/block-images.js#L24-L29? That shows how to intercept network requests, examine them, and either continue/abort the request.

Answer (score 55):

One option is to do the following:

```
  page.on('response', response => {
    if (response.url().endsWith("your/match"))
      console.log("response code: ", response.status());
      // do something here
  });
```

This still catches all requests, but allows you to filter and act on the event emitter.

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#event-response

Answer (score 16):

Filtered response (wait up to 11 seconds) body parsed as JSON with initially requested *PATCH* or *POST* method every time you will be call that:

```
const finalResponse = await page.waitForResponse(response => 
  response.url() === urlOfRequest 
  && (response.request().method() === 'PATCH' 
  || response.request().method() === 'POST'), 11);
let responseJson = await finalResponse.json();
console.log(responseJson);
```

Answer (score 9):

Since puppeteer `v1.6.0` (I guess) you can use [`page.waitForResponse(urlOrPredicate[, options])`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/9ef4153f6e3548ac3fd2ac75b4570343e53e3a0a/docs/api.md#pagewaitforresponseurlorpredicate-options)

Example usage from docs:

```
const firstResponse = await page.waitForResponse('https://example.com/resource');
const finalResponse = await page.waitForResponse(response =>
  response.url() === 'https://example.com' && response.status() === 200
);
return finalResponse.ok();
```

Answer (score 2):

I was using [`jest-puppeteer`](https://github.com/smooth-code/jest-puppeteer) and trying to test for a specific response code of my test server.  `page.goto()` [resolves to the response of the original request](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options).

Here is a simple test that a `404` response is returned when expected.

```
describe(`missing article page`, () => {
    let response;
    beforeAll(async () => {
        response = await page.goto('http://my-test-server/article/this-article-does-not-exist')
    })
    it('has an 404 response for missing articles', () => {
        expect(response.status()).toEqual(404)
    })

    it('has a footer', async () => {
        await expect(page).toMatch('My expected footer content')
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the xhr response simply do :

```
const firstResponse = await page.waitForResponse('https://example.com/resource')

// the NEXT line will extract the json response

console.log( await firstResponse.json() )
```